# xcodebuild printing too much logs

Tags: java, ios, logging, jenkins, xcodebuild

I'm trying to use 2 commands:

```
xcodebuild archive -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme Prod -configuration Prod -archivePath "${WORKSPACE}"/build/MyProject.xcarchive
```

and

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportProvisioningProfile "Prov Profile" -exportFormat IPA -exportPath "${WORKSPACE}"/build/MyProject.ipa -archivePath "${WORKSPACE}"/build/MyProject.xcarchive
```

However, there are way too many lines being logged - around 90k lines or so. normally this isn't a problem, but...

i'm running this on Jenkins, so the log is being logged in JVM memory and i'm getting some weird out of memory exceptions during my jenkins runs (which i think is because somehow with 64 builds, it's showing me 90k lines of logs as opposed to previously 50k lines of logs).

Is there a way to make it so that the logs are silent, until something fails? 90k logs is a LOT of lines to be logging for `xcodebuild`

Answer (score 3):

I have a hack around this:

have the output be piped to a file on the jenkins server, and `tail -f` that file to get the logs. you can then even email that tail (if the command had succeeded).

that way, you avoid logging into console, instead you log to file.

something like:

```
xcodebuild archive -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -scheme Prod -configuration Prod -archivePath "${WORKSPACE}"/build/MyProject.xcarchive > ~/dzt/tmp/archive_results.txt
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine, now I can get a separate log file for each action before the xcodebuild and for itself.